# Need help to find the VID/PID of the usb drive connected to the system through java code

Tags: java, usb

I need to find the vendor Id, Product Id of the usb drive connected to the system, through java code. Any suggestions...

Comment: OS indepedent or OS specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never interfaced with USB in Java before, but have a look at [JSR-80 (javax.usb) API](https://jcp.org/ja/jsr/detail?id=80). IBM [DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/index.html) have a tutorial (which can be useful).

Comment: Hi Elite, thanks for your answer. JSR-80 API is for Linux platforms. But I am using windows.

Comment: @Jack Sparrow, the API is **independent** of the OS, you will have to look for a windows library that implements this API.

Comment: All links are dead, but here is the fresh one: http://usb4java.org/quickstart/javax-usb.html

Comment: Not all links are dead though, only the IBM DeveloperWorks link is dead. Thanks for a recent library link update.

Answer (score 0):

If you need windows only use WMI. I do not think that cross-platform pure java solution exists at all. 
You have several ways to connect to WMI. Check out Jawin, Jintegra, Jinterop. All these libraries support WMI. You can also create WMI script using VBScript or JScript and run as an external command line tool from Java using `cscript` command.